# What is SO protocol for neither accepting an answer nor awarding a bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties, accepted-answer

I have recently asked an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204775/why-do-leins-control-keys-work-for-me-using-lein1-but-not-lein2) about a Clojure build tool, leiningen.

I did not let the original question become stale. I kept updating it with more information, as I tested and tried suggestions in one of the answers that asked me to reinstall.

The answers I have received so far have not helped.

Is it acceptable not to accept an answer nor award the bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The answers I have received so far have not helped.

That pretty much says it all. If it doesn't help, just let it sit.

- Don't upvote.
- Don't accept.
- Don't give the bounty.

> Is it acceptable not to accept an answer nor award the bounty?

Yes. But half the bounty will be automatically awarded to the high-scoring new answer that picks up 2 upvotes. (or not at all if none qualify)

---

Leave it open (unaccepted) and maybe someone in the future will come along and answer it.

Comment: But a bounty will be automatically awarded in some situations if the OP didn't award it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is acceptable.

You are never forced to accept an answer, especially if it did not help you. The bounty on the other hand, *can* be auto-awarded by the system if you let it lapse, to an answer with at least +2 score and posted after you started the bounty:

> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty. Answers accepted before the bounty period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.
>
> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is awarded half the bounty amount.

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to leave all answers unaccepted, and this is perfectly acceptable if you don't receive a solution.

However, if any of your answers has a score of +2 or more when the bounty runs out, half the bounty amount will be given to it automatically. You cannot prevent this.

You could try flagging your question for moderator attention and ask for your bounty to be refunded, but I wouldn't count on it happening, as your case isn't that uncommon.

Comment: It is rare for a bounty to be refunded; I don't think there is any point in flagging in this specific case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yep. which is why I said "I wouldn't count on it happening". I put it in the answer for future visitors, who might have a better claim to a refund.

Comment: I willingly gave up the bounty fare and square. I'd rather have a good answer.